# Number of roots of a polynomial of non-integer degree

Tags: polynomials

How many roots does a polynomial-like function of degree $n$ have if $n$ is a rational or an irrational number?

Comment: What _is_ a polynomial of non-integer degree? That's not a standard concept -- something with non-integral exponents is not usually called a "polynomial".

Comment: It is not a polynomial then.

Comment: a polynomial is defined as to have a positive integer degree. Maybe you mean that the coefficients are rational/irrational?

Comment: The question can make sense for a function like $\sum a_ix^{d_i}$, where $a_i,d_i$ are real numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You mean something like $x^{\sqrt 7}+4x^2+x^{1/2}$? That's not usually called a polynomial at all -- it is implicit in the word "polynomial" that all of the exponents must be constant nonnegative integers.

A sum of terms of this form will generally only make sense for positive $x$. The number of positive real roots can still be bounded using [Descartes' rule of signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) if you sort the terms by decreasing exponents. In particular there cannot be more positive roots than there are terms.

(To see that this is true for *rational* exponents, substitute $y=x^{1/m}$ where $m$ is a common multiple of all the denominators, which makes the result an actual polynomial in $y$, with the same sign changes. By continuity, it then also has to be true for irrational exponents. If there are negative exponents, multiply through by a large enough power of $x$, which doesn't change the number of positive roots either).

Comment: "true for irrational exponents": annoyingly, $m$ becomes infinite.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The $m$ is only relevant in the rational-exponent case. Once you know there are at most number-of-sign-changes many roots with rational exponents, there are also at most that many roots with _irrational_ exponents. Namely, suppose you have a "polynomial" with irrational exponents and "too many" roots, then there will be one with rational exponents and just as many roots too, because the function values are continuous functions of the exponents.

Comment: Does that tells you how many roots an i-polynomial can have  in general ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I don't know what an "i-polynomial" is.

Answer (score 4):

A "generalized polynomial" with rational exponents can be turned to an ordinary polynomial by the change of variable $x=t^g$, where $g$ is the least common multiple of the denominators of all exponents.

Example:

$$4x^2-2\sqrt[3]x+3x^{4/7}=0$$
becomes
$$4t^{42}-2t^7+3t^{12}=0$$
which has $42$ (possibly complex) roots in $t$.

Things are less easy for irrational exponents as you need to choose some principal branch when taking the exponential ($z^r:=|z|^re^{ir\arg(z)}$), and a complex number then has a single irrational power (while it has $n$ $n^{th}$ roots). The fundamental theorem of algebra does not hold anymore, and usually you limit yourself to real positive values of the unknown $x$.

My guess (just a guess) is that for $x>0$, as every term is monotonous, the number of roots can lie between $0$ and the number of terms minus $1$.

Comment: What if n is an irrational number ?

Comment: The change of variables with $g$ as the LCM will not always give the lowest-degree polynomial possible, since the numerators may have a common divisor.